# Cannot fetch properly data from API

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am currently trying out React for a future project and trying to get myself up to speed on it.

Bear with me, due to some circumstances I didn't code for 2 years so I am extremely rusty.

Anyway, I need to get React to properly fetch some data about tasks written up, but no matter what I try it just doesn't work. I have a function written as

```
  getDataFromDb = () => {
fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/getTask")
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => this.setState({ tasks: data.tasks, isLoading: false }))
  .catch(error => this.setState({error, isLoading: false}));
};
```

Now my output inside the JSX file

```
<React.Fragment>
  <h1>Random User</h1>
  {error ? <p>{error.message}</p> : null}
  {!isLoading ? (
    tasks.map(task => {
      const { title, description } = task;
      return (
        <div key={title}>
          <p>Title: {title}</p>
          <p>Desc: {description}</p>
          <hr />
        </div>
      );
    })

  ) : (
    <h3>Loading...</h3>
  )}
</React.Fragment>
```

No matter what I try with my own database, it just doesn't want to work with React. I try API calls through Postman and everything gets sent and received without any problems, but React sends out an error "Failed to fetch".

In my server.js I have the following api call written

```
router.get("/getTask", (req, res) => {
Task.find((err, task) => {
if (err) return res.json({ success: false, error: err });
return res.json({ success: true, task: task });
  });
});
```

I have scoured Internet and Stack for some answers and examples, and, the dumbest thing is, if I use an external API (such as "https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?query=redux"), or any other, honestly, then it works fine. If it makes any difference, I use mLabs sandbox for MongoDB.

Any suggestions? Been stuck on this for the last 5 hours or so.

Comment: In `tasks.map()`, `tasks` is not defined. Either deconstruct state or use `this.state.tasks.map()` (assuming your JSX is the same component as the fetch)

Comment: if `postman` calls are fine, then probably `CORS` issue. Try your application on `firefox` and open the console tab to confirm if it's indeed cors issue. Read how to set up cors here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067966/how-to-allow-cors

Comment: Fixed this! Thought about the fact, that my authorization snippet works fine, but this doesnt. Turns out, instead of calling `http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/getTask`, had to call `api/getTask` instead. Thanks for all the tips!

Answer (score 1):

Your fetch request seems to be going to a localhost address and port. Make sure CORS is is set up correctly on your server to allow for incoming connections from the same address with a different port. Postman usually works for any server set up correctly regardless of CORS settings. I'm not sure about fetch, but with axios, if you print the error object, it should give you a lot more information to work with.

In addition, stever's comment is also correct in that tasks is not defined since you're not using this state task.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `getDataFromDb()` inside your component at any point during the lifecycle or if it's tied to an event, such as `onClick` on a button etc.

If you need it to load initially and your component is a function you can do the following

```
import React, {useState} from 'react;

function Component() {
 useState(() => {
   getDataFromDb,[])
return (
 <React.Fragment>
  <h1>Random User</h1>
  {error ? <p>{error.message}</p> : null}
  {!isLoading ? (
    tasks.map(task => {
      const { title, description } = task;
        <div key={title}>
          <p>Title: {title}</p>
          <p>Desc: {description}</p>
          <hr />
        </div>
     })

   ) : (
    <h3>Loading...</h3>
   )}
  </React.Fragment>
 )
}
```

or inside `componentDidMount()` if you are using a class component

The `axios` library is really good wrapper for fetching data :)